# Is there any way to debug gpu Render Graph in D3D application use visual studio 2015?

Tags: windows, gpu, visual-studio-debugging, direct3d

Is there any way debug to gpu Render Graph in D3D like GPU Frame Capture in Xcode ,which can show any GPU render input and output? GPU Frame Capture in Xcodecan show Render Graph like this [Render Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRkhX.png).
Now I can debug d3d render state by Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer [Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mljd3.png). But I want to know the GPU render input and output visiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to debug gpu Render Graph in D3D application use
>   visual studio 2015?

I am afraid that you can not get what you want. **In fact**, Visual Studio 2015 cannot show the GPU render input and output by default.

**As a suggestion**, I think you can try to use [Graphics Debugger tool](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition) **which is most likely to meet your needs**.

You can refer to [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-2019_4) to download `NVIDIA Nsight`. When you finish the installation, select `Nsight`-->`Start Graphics Debugging`.

**In addition**, if this tool does not help you, I suggest you could post a feature request in our [User Voice forum(DC)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)----suggest a feature to share your idea and the team will seriously consider your idea and give you a satisfactory reply.